# Classification with ordered sequences of samples

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, categorical-data

Assume that we have a dataset that is structured in the following manner:
[image]

Features are numeric and target is a class from $0$ to $11$. The objective is to assign each row to one of the available classes, predicting for a new unseen group.

What differentiates this case from standard multi-class classification is that the classifier must take into account the ordering of the samples that belong to the same group, given some constraints about what class cannot come before or after another.

An initial idea was to train a tree-based classifier with a standard multi-class setting and then post-process its results to satisfy the ordering constraints.

Is there a way to integrate the constraints to the training process? Can you suggest a classification method that could achieve this?

Comment: This is done frequently in coreference resolution in NLP; the literature on structured prediction for coreference resolution may be helpful.

Comment: Are the constraints simple like A must come before B, B before C, etc. Or are the constraints more difficult?

Comment: What are you predicting, 'group' or 'target'?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The constraints are not as straightforward as a complete ordering of the classes but are not too difficult, I believe. It's basically that some classes cannot come after some other ones. As for your other question, I am predicting "target", but the prediction process is applied for a whole new unseen group.

Comment: I had problems with the interpretation of this sentence *"The objective is to assign each row to one of the available classes, predicting for a new unseen group."* The part 'predicting for a new unseen group' made me think that it was about predicting the group label. Possibly the following is easier  *"The objective is to assign each row to one of the available target classes, for a new unseen group."*

Comment: Possibly something like a variant of the pool adjacent violators algorithm might work.